# sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I switched to a new machine. I used git pull from Heroku to grab a working project. When I try to push the same thing back up I get the following error. I tried bundle exec rake -P and it works fine, but doesn't fix anything.

```
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/
gems/useragents-0.1.6/lib/useragents/fetch
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/useragents-0.1.6/lib/useragents
.rb:2:in `require_relative'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/useragents-0.1.6/lib/useragents
.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runt
ime.rb:82:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runt
ime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runt
ime.rb:77:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runt
ime.rb:77:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runt
ime.rb:66:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runt
ime.rb:66:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler.rb:1
08:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_modul
e.rb:28:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_modul
e.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/applicatio
n.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/applicatio
n.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/applicatio
n.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/applicatio
n.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/applicatio
n.rb:79:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/applicatio
n.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/applicatio
n.rb:77:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<to
p (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20d
ffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detec
t rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: rake aborted!
remote: LoadError: cannot load such file -- /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/us
eragents-0.1.6/lib/useragents/fetch
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/useragents-0.1.6/lib/useragents.rb:2:i
n `require_relative'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/useragents-0.1.6/lib/useragents.rb:2:i
n `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:
82:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:
82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:
77:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:
77:in `block in require'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:
66:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:
66:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `
require'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28
:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28
:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:68
7:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96
:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:17
8:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95
:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79
:in `block in run'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:17
8:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77
:in `run'
remote: /tmp/build_8e4d8dc7b703ee5d91164565285a1d93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (requ
ired)>'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:755:in `rake'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_prec
ompile_rake_task'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:132:in `log'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake
_task'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:776:in `allow_git'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:103:in `block in compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:92:in `compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:57:in `block in compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:55:in `compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:132:in `log'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a
3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

.

```
BLAZER_DATABASE_URL: postgres://... 
DATABASE_URL: postgres://... 
LANG: en_US.UTF-8 
RACK_ENV: production RAILS_ENV: production 
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled 
SECRET_KEY_BASE: ...
```

Comment: What do you see when you run `bundle exec rake -P`?

Comment: What looks like a list of available rake commands

Comment: Who downvoted this? How could this question be any more clear/straight forward

Comment: I don't know, is there something in your logs?

Comment: Heroku logs just say build failed, the build logs are above

Comment: Run `heroku config` what do you see?

Comment: BLAZER_DATABASE_URL:      postgres://...
DATABASE_URL:             postgres://...
LANG:                     en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV:                 production
RAILS_ENV:                production
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled
SECRET_KEY_BASE:          ...

Comment: Can you see something wrong? can you add it to your question?

Comment: It all looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line `gem 'useragents'` from `Gemfile` fixes it. No idea why